# How to paginate using Zend2/Doctrine combo (using the Doctrine provided paginator adapter)?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I've been looking for examples/guides on how to do what I asked.

I've found several examples and "best" I've found yet is this one => http://blog.loftdigital.com/blog/doctrine-plus-zf2-tips-pagination

**2 problems**

1. I'm not really sure if my paginator object contains the right number of records (I limited it to 5 records on my adapter object)
2. I don't know how to traverse the paginator object in my view file. it seems **very** complex. I did a print_r on the object enclosing the thing in a pre HTML tag and it's easily 20+K lines on my text editor (after copy/paste)

Can you please help?

thank you very much

---

**my controller code based from the example** (not really working but no zend/doctrine errors too. problem is that it gives me all the records instead of just 10)

```
$directory->populate($form->getData());
$adapter = new DoctrineAdapter(new ORMPaginator($directoryDao->searchStaffDirectory($this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder(), $directory)));
$adapter->getItems(0, 5);
//var_dump($adapter->getItems(0, 5)); **//display the corrent number of records**

$paginator = new Paginator($adapter);
$paginator->setDefaultItemCountPerPage(5);
$page = (int)$this->params()->fromQuery("page");
if($page) $paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);

return array('staffList' => $paginator);
```

**my DirectoryDAO class** (the relevant parts)

```
public function searchStaffDirectory(QueryBuilder $queryBuilder, DirectoryModel $directory) {
    $conditions = new Andx;

    $queryBuilder
            ->select('directory')
            ->from('Directory\Model\DirectoryModel', 'directory');
    if (strlen($directory->surnameSearch)) {
         $conditions->add($queryBuilder->expr()->like('directory.surnameSearch', "'".preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $directory->surnameSearch)."%'"));
    }
    if (strlen($directory->surnameSoundsSearch)) {
         $conditions->add($queryBuilder->expr()->like('directory.surnameSoundsSearch', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $directory->surnameSoundsSearch)));
    }
    if (strlen($directory->firstnameSearch)) {
         $conditions->add($queryBuilder->expr()->like('directory.firsnameSearch', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $directory->firstnameSearch)));
    }
    if (strlen($directory->telephoneNumber)) {
         $conditions->add($queryBuilder->expr()->like('directory.telephoneNumber', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $directory->telephoneNumber)));
    }
    if (strlen($directory->departmentSearch)) {
         $conditions->add($queryBuilder->expr()->like('directory.departmentSearch', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $directory->departmentSearch)));
    }
    if (strlen($directory->roleSearch)) {
         $conditions->add($queryBuilder->expr()->like('directory.roleSearch', preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $directory->roleSearch)));
    }
    if ($conditions->count()) {
            $queryBuilder->andWhere($conditions);
    }
    $queryBuilder
            ->orderBy('directory.surname');

    return $queryBuilder->getQuery();
}
```

**my DirectoryModel class**

```
<?php

namespace Directory\Model;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping;

use Zend\InputFilter\Factory;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

/**
 * @Mapping\Entity
 * @Mapping\Table(name="staffdirectory_vw")
 */
class DirectoryModel {
    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Id
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_pk", type="integer", unique=true)
     */
    protected $pk;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_id", type="string")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     *
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_parent_id", type="string")
     */
    protected $parentId;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_auth_code", type="string")
     */
    protected $fan;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_full_name", type="string")
     */
    protected $fullname;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_name_title", type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_first_pref_name", type="string")
     */
    protected $firstname;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_surname", type="string")
     */
    protected $surname;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_bldg_long_desc", type="string")
     */
    protected $building;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_display_department", type="string")
     */
    protected $department;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_alias", type="string")
     */
    protected $email;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_alias_list", type="string")
     */
    protected $emailList;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_entity_type", type="string")
     */
    protected $entityType;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_org_heirarchy", type="string")
     */
    protected $organisationalHeirarchy;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_role", type="string")
     */
    protected $role;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_room", type="string")
     */
    protected $room;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_tele_number", type="string")
     */
    protected $telephoneNumber;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_tele_number_formats", type="string")
     */
    protected $telephoneNumberFormats;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_tele_rank", type="string")
     */
    protected $teleRank;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_url", type="string")
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_search_surname", type="string")
     */
    protected $surnameSearch;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_surname_soundex", type="string")
     */
    protected $surnameSoundsSearch;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_search_first_name", type="string")
     */
    protected $firstnameSearch;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_search_department", type="string")
     */
    protected $departmentSearch;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_search_role", type="string")
     */
    protected $roleSearch;

    /**
     * 
     * @Mapping\Column(name="mytable_tele_directory", type="string")
     */
    protected $teleDirectory;

    protected $inputFilter;

    /**
     * Magic getter to expose protected properties.
     * 
     * @param string $property
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function __get($property) {
        return $this->$property;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * Magic setter to save protected properties.
     * 
     * @param string $property
     * @param mixed $value
     */
    public function __set($property, $value) {
        $this->$property = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Convert the object to an array.
     * 
     * @return array
     */
    public function getArrayCopy() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

    /**
     * Populate from an array.
     * 
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function populate($data = array()) {
        $this->pk = isset($data['pk']) ? $data['pk'] : null;
        $this->id = isset($data['id']) ? $data['id'] : null;
        $this->fan = isset($data['fan']) ? $data['fan'] : null;
        $this->fullname = isset($data['fullname']) ? $data['fullname'] : null;
        $this->surname = isset($data['surname']) ? $data['surname'] : null;
        $this->building = isset($data['building']) ? $data['building'] : null;
        $this->department = isset($data['department']) ? $data['department'] : null;
        $this->email = isset($data['email']) ? $data['email'] : null;
        $this->emailList = isset($data['emailList']) ? $data['emailList'] : null;
        $this->entityType = isset($data['entityType']) ? $data['entityType'] : null;
        $this->organisationalHeirarchy = isset($data['organisationalHeirarchy']) ? $data['organisationalHeirarchy'] : null;
        $this->role = isset($data['role']) ? $data['role'] : null;
        $this->room = isset($data['room']) ? $data['room'] : null;
        $this->telephoneNumber = isset($data['telephoneNumber']) ? $data['telephoneNumber'] : null;
        $this->telephoneNumberFormats = isset($data['telephoneNumberFormats']) ? $data['telephoneNumberFormats'] : null;
        $this->teleRank = isset($data['teleRank']) ? $data['teleRank'] : null;
        $this->url = isset($data['url']) ? $data['url'] : null;
        $this->surnameSearch = isset($data['surnameSearch']) ? $data['surnameSearch'] : null;
        $this->surnameSoundsSearch = isset($data['surnameSoundsSearch']) ? $data['surnameSoundsSearch'] : null;
        $this->firstnameSearch = isset($data['firstnameSearch']) ? $data['firstnameSearch'] : null;
        $this->departmentSearch = isset($data['departmentSearch']) ? $data['departmentSearch'] : null;
        $this->roleSearch = isset($data['roleSearch']) ? $data['roleSearch'] : null;
        $this->teleDirectory = isset($data['teleDirectory']) ? $data['teleDirectory'] : null;
    }

    public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter) {
        throw new \Exception("Not used");
    }

    public function getInputFilter() {
        if (!$this->inputFilter) {
            $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
            $factory = new Factory();

            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name'     => 'surnameSearch',
                    'required' => false,
                    'filters'  => array(
                            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                            array('name' => 'StringToUpper'),
                            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    ),
                    'validators' => array(
                            array(
                                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                                    'options' => array(
                                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                            'min'      => 1,
                                            'max'      => 30,
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            )));
            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name'     => 'surnameSoundsSearch',
                    'required' => false,
                    'filters'  => array(
                            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                            array('name' => 'StringToUpper'),
                            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    ),
                    'validators' => array(
                            array(
                                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                                    'options' => array(
                                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                            'min'      => 1,
                                            'max'      => 30,
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            )));
            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name'     => 'firstnameSearch',
                    'required' => false,
                    'filters'  => array(
                            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                            array('name' => 'StringToUpper'),
                            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    ),
                    'validators' => array(
                            array(
                                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                                    'options' => array(
                                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                            'min'      => 1,
                                            'max'      => 30,
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            )));
            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name'     => 'telephoneNumberSearch',
                    'required' => false,
                    'filters'  => array(
                            array('name' => 'Int'),
                    ),
            )));
            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name'     => 'departmentSearch',
                    'required' => false,
                    'filters'  => array(
                            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                            array('name' => 'StringToUpper'),
                            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    ),
                    'validators' => array(
                            array(
                                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                                    'options' => array(
                                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                            'min'      => 1,
                                            'max'      => 30,
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            )));
            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                    'name'     => 'roleeSearch',
                    'required' => false,
                    'filters'  => array(
                            array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                            array('name' => 'StringToUpper'),
                            array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                    ),
                    'validators' => array(
                            array(
                                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                                    'options' => array(
                                            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                                            'min'      => 1,
                                            'max'      => 30,
                                    ),
                            ),
                    ),
            )));

            $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
        }

        return $this->inputFilter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `DoctrineAdapter` is actually `DoctrineORMModule\Paginator\Adapter\DoctrinePaginator` just you imported it with a different name. If not, then this is the class you should be using.

Your controller should be:

```
$directory->populate($form->getData());
$adapter = new DoctrineAdapter(new ORMPaginator($directoryDao->searchStaffDirectory($this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder(), $directory)));

$paginator = new Paginator($adapter);
$paginator->setItemCountPerPage(5);
$page = (int)$this->params()->fromQuery("page");
$paginator->setCurrentPageNumber($page);

return array('staffList' => $paginator);
```

No need to call `getItems` and when you cast `$page` to int then it will automatically default to the first page if no page parameter is passed.

Using the paginator in the view is more complex. First you need to implement a view script that renders the paginator. There are a number of example scripts in the ZF2 documentation which you can either use outright or base your own paginator off:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.paginator.usage.html#example-pagination-controls

To use the paginator in your actual view, you can iterate over it like any other query result to display your items:

```
<?php foreach($staffList as $staff): ?>

    Firstname: <?php echo $staff->firstname; ?>

    etc.

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This will only display items currently for the current page that the paginator is on, which is what you want.

To display the paginator controls:

```
<?php echo $this->paginationControl($staffList, '<paginator type>', '<my paginator view script>', array('route' => '<route name>')); ?>
```

Paginator type can be: All, Elastic, Jumping, Sliding and determines how and what page numbers are displayed on the paginator controls. Sliding is the default and is most likely the best choice.